# How can I use a LifecycleListener in a gerrit plugin?

Tags: java, guice, gerrit

I'm writing a gerrit plugin and want to close network connections on plugin restart/shutdown. This can be done using a `LifecycleListener`.

As far as I know, there are two modes of operation for a gerrit plugin concerning Guice. One is to not declare anything in the Manifest and use auto-registration for everything, using annotations like `@Listen` and `@Export`. The other is to create a Guice module and do all wiring manually in that module.

I'd like to use auto-registration, but I can't make it work with a `LifecycleListener`. Adding a `@Listen` annotation has no effect, the Listener is getting ignored.

My code looks like this (minimized):

```
@Listen
@Singleton
public class CommitValidationTest implements CommitValidationListener {
        @Listen
        public static class Lifecycle implements LifecycleListener {
                @Override
                public void start() {
                    // write to log
                }

                @Override
                public void stop() {
                    // write to log
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you register a interceptor for `@Listen` annotation?

Comment: No, but the `@Listen` annotation is defined by gerrit and used for auto-registration of plugin `@ExtensionPoint`s.

Comment: Does your plugin load successfully?  I tried adding a `LifecycleListener` on the commit message length validation plugin (a core Gerrit plugin) using the same method in your example and it fails to load the plugin with "com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.InvalidPluginException: Cannot register com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.validators.CommitMessageLengthValidation$Lifecycle, server does not accept com.google.gerrit.extensions.events.LifecycleListener".

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work. But IMO it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gathered that `LifecycleListener`s can't be used in combination with AutoRegistration.

Here's why: In order for the `@Listen` annotation to work, the `@ExtensionPoint` interface which is implemented by the class (in this case `LifecycleListener`) must have a `DynamicItem`, `DynamicSet` or `DynamicMap` definition in a Guice module, which isn't the case for `LifecycleListener`.

Comment: I've raised this as an issue on the Gerrit issue tracker [1].

[1] https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2101